# How to access file upload selected file without changing page using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, file-upload, input, input-type-file

I need to create a file upload field which I have below:

```
<div class="col-xs-4 col-md-4 form-group">
    <label for="file-upload" >File Upload</label>
    <input type="file" id="file-upload"/>
</div>
```

How do I access the contents of the selected file without going to another page or adding anything to the URL in Javascript?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this simple code

```js
var inputFile = document.getElementById("file-upload");

inputFile.addEventListener("change", function(){
    var files = inputFile.files;
    console.log(files[0]);
    alert(files[0].name);
});
```

```html
<input type="file" id="file-upload"/>
```

Comment: Yeahthat is what I have but how do I get the contents of the file I choose other than its name

Comment: All content of file is in object that named files. see your console after selecting file.

Comment: where in the console will I see the text that is in the file? for instance am I able call files[0].text?

Comment: After selecting file, content of selected file writed in console. To see browser console press F12 key then click on console tab on top of opened panel.

Comment: Yes I see the file in the console, how do I get the text from the file I have selected?

Comment: for instance, I have a text file with "hello world" in it. I see the file details in the console. How do I get "hello world" from that file?

Comment: Exuse me for my late. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27522979/read-a-local-textfile-using-javascript

Comment: That is awesome . Thank You so much