# Reading selected file without submitting and saving. PHP - javascript

Tags: javascript, php

I try to read file (id="file") after selected and return character count to paragraph (id="count"). I want it without submitting, without clicking any other button and without saving. I've tried jquery and "vanilla" javascript.
Here is my code with "vanilla":

HTML:

```
<input type="file" id="file" name="file" onchange="fileCount(this)" />
<p id="count"></p>
```

Javascript:

```
function fileCount(file) {

    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {
        // code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById("count").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;

        }
    };
    xmlhttp.open('POST', 'fileCount.php', true);
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('X-FileName',file.name);
    xmlhttp.send(file);}
```

PHP:

```
if(!empty($_FILES['file'])) {

    if ($_FILES['file']['error'] === 0) {
        $temp = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];

        $ext = (explode(".",$temp));
        $ext = end($ext);
        $file = "";
        switch ($ext) {
            case "pdf":
                $text = pdf2text($temp);
                $file = strlen(utf8_decode($text));
                print_r( "<p id='count'>Počet: " . $file . "</p>");
                break;
            case "docx":
                $text = docx2text($temp);
                $file = strlen(utf8_decode($text));
                print_r( "<p id='count'>Počet: " . $file . "</p>");
                break;
            case "odt":
                $text = odt2text($temp);
                $file = strlen(utf8_decode($text));
                print_r( "<p id='count'>Počet: " . $file . "</p>");
                break;
            case "rtf":
                $text = rtf2text($temp);
                $file = strlen(utf8_decode($text));
                print_r( "<p id='count'>Počet: " . $file . "</p>");
                break;
            //case "txt":
                $text = file_get_contents($temp);
                $file = strlen(utf8_decode($text));
                print_r( "<p id='count'>Počet: " . $file . "</p>");
                break;
            default:
                print_r( "Wrong file format" );
        }
    }
```

}

and nothing is returning. Please help, what is wrong. Thank you

Comment: You can't just post a file like that. You need to look in to [FormData](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21044798/how-to-use-formdata-for-ajax-file-upload). And if you already have the `<p id="count"></p>` tag on you page, you don't need to return the tag in your response.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson The OP is writing code targeting a browser from (literally) the last century, i doubt FormData is available!

Comment: @Steve - I can't see that he mentions that anywhere? Looking at the code, I'm assuming that the script is a copied/pasted from somewhere else. But I can be wrong and you make a good point. (I know that I'm probably making an ass out of u and me by assuming)

Comment: @MagnusEriksson no, im being the ass, i am just amazed how many people copy that damned snippet without even reading it.. OP if your are targeting modern browsers, then filereader could be an option, no need for the server post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27522979/read-a-local-textfile-using-javascript