# Run javascript without web server

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js, webserver

I have a `index.html` page and link to another javascript file `d3.html`. In `d3.html` javaScript file the javaScript code do some interesting stuff with a local file `amazon.txt` (in my computer). I code and test in local XAMPP web server and everything works fine. However, if i close the XAMPP (web server), the `d3.html`cannot be loaded. The `d3.html` have an error `Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes`

In `index.html`:

```
<p><a href="d3.html">link</a></p>
```

in `d3.html`:

```
$.get('amazonCut.txt', function (data) {
          // interesting stuff
        }
```

If I close XAMPP, index.html can be loaded but d3.js cannot. I browsed the stackoverflow and changed above code to:

```
<p><a href="http://localhost/d3.html">link for complete result </a></p>
```

and

```
$.get('https://localhost/amazonCut.txt', function (data) {
          // interesting stuff
        }
```

but it won't work. The reason I am doing this because the instructor only clicks the index.html file when grading without setting any web server.

Comment: You need a web server to load local files. If you put the content of that file (be it a txt, csv, tsv etc) as a variable in the JS code, you don't need the server.

Comment: You have shut down your XAMPP server and then issuing it a request? That's why you are getting the error.

Comment: how to read the file and put as a variable?@GerardoFurtado

Comment: I need to run it without XAMPP. @Shubhranshu

Comment: @SHE What's the file in question?

Comment: You'll need to have a web server, but luckily there are [plenty of ways to spin up a web server](https://gist.github.com/willurd/5720255) without any configuration. Since you're using PHP, [`php -S`](http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.webserver.php) seems like an obvious choice.

Comment: amazonCut.txt Thanks@GerardoFurtado

Comment: Your answer doesn't help at all: can you paste the link of the file?

Comment: If it is in local drive, then you can take help from this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27522979/read-a-local-text-file-using-javascript

Comment: It is a local file in my computer@GerardoFurtado

Comment: What @Shubhranshu said, how ever, if I were you, I would just load the contents of that file into a Javascript variable and go ahead with the experiment, if that's not a possibility then create a <div> element and load it with the same data and just hide it.

Comment: how to write that tho? @Krylor

Comment: @SHE
Storage in d3.html

    <div id='id_amazoncut' style='display:none'>[contents of your file go in here]</div>
Use it in Jquery as follows
$( document ).ready(function() {
    var amazoncut = $("#id_amazoncut");
  // Do what you want with the data
});