# How to read object written through cordova file plugin?

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, cordova-plugins, filereader

I read on Cordova's [documentation](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-file/index.html#sample-create-files-and-directories-write-read-and-append-files-) for android platform a code snipped and tried to use it for writing a JS object on a text file. The object gets successfully written but when I read it with FileReader API I can't get output as expected.

```
function writeFile(fileEntry, dataObj, isAppend) {
    // Create a FileWriter object for our FileEntry (log.txt).
    fileEntry.createWriter(function (fileWriter) {

        fileWriter.onwriteend = function() {
            console.log("Successful file read...");
            readFile(fileEntry);
        };

        fileWriter.onerror = function (e) {
            console.log("Failed file read: " + e.toString());
        };

        // If we are appending data to file, go to the end of the file.
        if (isAppend) {
            try {
                fileWriter.seek(fileWriter.length);
            }
            catch (e) {
                console.log("file doesn't exist!");
            }
        }
        fileWriter.write(dataObj);
    });
}

function readFile(fileEntry) {

    fileEntry.file(function (file) {
        var reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onloadend = function() {
            console.log("Successful file read: " + this.result);

            //displayFileData(fileEntry.fullPath + ": " + this.result);
        };
        reader.onload = function(){
            k=reader.readAsText(file);

        };
       reader.readAsText(file);

    },onErrorLoadFs );
}
```

Format of object I want to read :

```
function sub(name,absent,present){
    this.name=name;
    this.absent=absent;
    this.present=present;

}

var S = new sub('Physics',1,3);
var k= new sub();
```

**What exactly I want to do :**

I am writing an object `S` on the file which appears like this when opened

```
{"name":"Physics","absent":1, "present" : 3}
```

Now after reading the file (which in my case is `filetoAppend.txt`) I want to assign these values to another object `k` so that when I run `k.name`, `Physics` is shown as output.

console output

```
k
"{"name":"Physics","absent":1,"present":3}"
k.name
undefined
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the Cordova File Plugin, there are two essential pieces of information to remember:

1.Like all Cordova plugins, you have to wait for the `deviceready` event before you try anything,

2.Then, Use `window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(<path>, <successHandler>, <errorHandler>)`

`window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL()` returns a `FileEntry` or `DirectoryEntry` instance (depending on whether you gave a file or a directory as path as its first parameter), which you can then work with.

**WRITING TO A FILE**

```
document.addEventListener('deviceready', onDeviceReady, false);  
function onDeviceReady() {  
    function writeToFile(fileName, data) {
        data = JSON.stringify(data, null, '\t');
        window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(cordova.file.dataDirectory, function (directoryEntry) {
            directoryEntry.getFile(fileName, { create: true }, function (fileEntry) {
                fileEntry.createWriter(function (fileWriter) {
                    fileWriter.onwriteend = function (e) {
                        // for real-world usage, you might consider passing a success callback
                        console.log('Write of file "' + fileName + '"" completed.');
                    };

                    fileWriter.onerror = function (e) {
                        // you could hook this up with our global error handler, or pass in an error callback
                        console.log('Write failed: ' + e.toString());
                    };

                    var blob = new Blob([data], { type: 'text/plain' });
                    fileWriter.write(blob);
                }, errorHandler.bind(null, fileName));
            }, errorHandler.bind(null, fileName));
        }, errorHandler.bind(null, fileName));
    }

    writeToFile('example.json', { foo: 'bar' });
}
```

**WRITING FROM FILE**

```
document.addEventListener('deviceready', onDeviceReady, false);  
function onDeviceReady() {  
    function readFromFile(fileName, cb) {
        var pathToFile = cordova.file.dataDirectory + fileName;
        window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(pathToFile, function (fileEntry) {
            fileEntry.file(function (file) {
                var reader = new FileReader();

                reader.onloadend = function (e) {
                    cb(JSON.parse(this.result));
                };

                reader.readAsText(file);
            }, errorHandler.bind(null, fileName));
        }, errorHandler.bind(null, fileName));
    }

    var fileData;
    readFromFile('data.json', function (data) {
        fileData = data;
    });
}
```

**cb is the callback function that you need to pass when calling this function**

For full reference use:https://www.neontribe.co.uk/cordova-file-plugin-examples/

**Updated based on your updated Question**

In **reader.onloadend** you can get the result of the file and assign to your output object k or can call callback function incase.

```
reader.onloadend = function (e) {
   //cb(JSON.parse(this.result));
   var k=JSON.parse(this.result);
   console.log(k.name + ", " + k.absent+ ", " + k.present);
  };
```

```js
var k = JSON.parse('{"name":"Physics","absent":1, "present" : 3}');
console.log(k.name + ", " + k.absent + ", " + k.present);
```

Comment: What is cb in `cb(JSON.parse(this.result));`?

Comment: @GaganRajput -It is a callback function that you need to pass when calling this function

Comment: I don't see it defined anywhere.

Comment: Buddy as it is async process so you need to pass a call back function when you calling readFromFile method. Pass the reference of a JavaScript method that will handle the result

Comment: I have edited my question. Also consider reading example given in documentation of cordova-plugin-file whose link is also included in the question.

Comment: I understand your problem. So in callback you can get JSON data of file and can set in object **k**. **callback function is just a function that u want to execute from another function** For callback understanding u can refer https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_callback.asp

Comment: Is it possible to do what I'm trying to do. If so can you help me with the respective code. I am new to JS and Cordova but I have studied data file handling in C++ in school.

Comment: @GaganRajput  Hi I seached a lot for you and find the best example for you:
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cordova/cordova_file_system.htm

This link have very clear steps you have to do and also have the javascript callback function.

Do not forget to upvote and accept the answer if found useful.Thanks

Comment: Thank you for devoting your time and helping me but, I already know that and things which are described on that page can be done on my code too. The main problem is I can't feed data into objects of my code.

Comment: ok tell me from where you are calling **readFile(fileEntry)** function and also tell me in your code are you getting data in **k** using console log or alert?

Comment: since I already written an object to a file `JSON.parse(this.result)` return some error like `unexpected token o`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44038201/save-json-data-to-text-file-and-read-it

Comment: Hi @NullPointer would you mind take at look at this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67565787/promisify-filereader-onload-got-typeerror-cannot-read-property-then-of-undefi
My initial thought was to wrap the whole thing in a promise so that it will do the next after the reading is finished, but after reading your post makes me wonder adding a callback works too. But i dont know how.

Comment: It seems like the author thinks supporting promise is not a good idea: https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file/issues/344. Also I try to use your code but ` directoryEntry.getFile` raised `Unresolved function or method getFile()` and `fileEntry.file` raised `Unresolved function or method file()` Been scratching my heads for the last few days. Any help will be much much appreciated.